# MacBook Pro 2017 randomly restarts during sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash

I have a new MBP 15 inch, 2017 w/touchbar (MacOS 10.12.5) and it restarts randomly during sleep. I could not find any pattern in kernel panic logs (few latest attached).

```
Anonymous UUID:       8E5573F2-69B7-BEC8-75D7-17581A679C02

Tue Jun  6 11:06:13 2017

*** Panic Report ***
Panic(CPU 0): Unresponsive processor (this CPU did not acknowledge interrupts) TLB state:0x0
RAX: 0x000000000001c8a0, RBX: 0xffffff81b04bb000, RCX: 0x00000000000038c8, RDX: 0xffffff8049b9c040
RSP: 0xffffff81d0df4e00, RBP: 0xffffff81d0df4e10, RSI: 0xffffff91ff9958c8, RDI: 0xffffff91ff992000
R8:  0xffffff81d0df4e70, R9:  0x0000000000000001, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0xffffff801228a810
R12: 0x0000000000000072, R13: 0xffffff9227ba3d10, R14: 0xffffff81b04bb080, R15: 0xffffff81d0df5000
RFL: 0x0000000000000082, RIP: 0xffffff7f95562a5a, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81d0df4ca0 : 0xffffff8011bfe6c1 
0xffffff81d0df4d00 : 0xffffff8011a9b8bf 
0xffffff81d0df4e10 : 0xffffff7f95562a28 
0xffffff81d0df4e40 : 0xffffff7f95564df7 
0xffffff81d0df4ef0 : 0xffffff7f92350d6b 
0xffffff81d0df4f40 : 0xffffff7f94a3dd46 
0xffffff81d0df4f50 : 0xffffff7f94a4602f 
0xffffff81d0df4f70 : 0xffffff8011bfe6de 
0xffffff81d0df4fd0 : 0xffffff8011a9b759 
0xffffff9227ba3e60 : 0xffffff7f93fba530 
0xffffff9227ba3e90 : 0xffffff7f93fbc20c 
0xffffff9227ba3ee0 : 0xffffff80120bc69f 
0xffffff9227ba3f30 : 0xffffff80120baf01 
0xffffff9227ba3f80 : 0xffffff80120ba4e6 
0xffffff9227ba3fb0 : 0xffffff8011a988f7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BD9FCDEF-30CB-3911-B247-EE51DD069C76]@0xffffff7f92332000->0xffffff7f92366fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(5.0)[65E05472-6AE7-3308-8CC8-FA6CB0DB2AEE]@0xffffff7f94a37000->0xffffff7f94a96fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f92380000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BD9FCDEF-30CB-3911-B247-EE51DD069C76]@0xffffff7f92332000
         com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI(4.5.4)[06994150-CD32-34E1-9870-D3FE6F1DD329]@0xffffff7f93fb8000->0xffffff7f93fd4fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f92380000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BD9FCDEF-30CB-3911-B247-EE51DD069C76]@0xffffff7f92332000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily(6.5.7)[151493AF-E856-395F-9F2D-151853A404FF]@0xffffff7f92f37000
         com.apple.kext.AMD9510Controller(1.5.1)[6975A408-4E39-3703-856B-8F25A610A6A0]@0xffffff7f95561000->0xffffff7f9573dfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f92380000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BD9FCDEF-30CB-3911-B247-EE51DD069C76]@0xffffff7f92332000
            dependency: com.apple.kext.AMDSupport(1.5.1)[90685444-2E99-3B31-ACAA-5CD4D03E506E]@0xffffff7f94b54000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(515.3)[A423518D-758D-3021-A111-A59F44D760A8]@0xffffff7f9315c000
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.kext.AMD9510Controller(1.5.1)[6975A408-4E39-3703-856B-8F25A610A6A0]@0xffffff7f95561000->0xffffff7f9573dfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f92380000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BD9FCDEF-30CB-3911-B247-EE51DD069C76]@0xffffff7f92332000
            dependency: com.apple.kext.AMDSupport(1.5.1)[90685444-2E99-3B31-ACAA-5CD4D03E506E]@0xffffff7f94b54000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(515.3)[A423518D-758D-3021-A111-A59F44D760A8]@0xffffff7f9315c000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
16F73

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FB2170A8-257D-3C64-B14D-BC06CC94E34C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000011800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8011a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8011900000
System model name: MacBookPro13,3 (Mac-A5C67F76ED83108C)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 187868359686560
last loaded kext at 187789987183922: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm   5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f958bb000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 187633104319719: com.apple.driver.TestDeviceVCOMACMData   1.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f958a8000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.eset.kext.esets_kac 401.09.70f01
com.logitech.manager.kernel.driver  6.40.1
com.apple.driver.TestDeviceVCOMACMData  1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   279.48
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.17
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.14.47
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.4f18
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   1.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphics  10.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.14.47
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4100   1.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost 1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMD9510Controller    1.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer   10.2.5
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.50.19
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 114
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1150.10.1a2
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 279.48
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.4f18
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.14.47
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   159.7
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.15
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   516.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.5.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.14.47
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    311.13
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    515.3
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394.50.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBiBridge    1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540.30.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   199
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  368.16
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    76.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    49
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  49
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.0.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.50.16
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.4f18
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff8011bde5fd): "TLB invalidation IPI timeout: " "CPU(s) failed to respond to interrupts, unresponsive CPU bitmap: 0x1, NMIPI acks: orig: 0x0, now: 0x1"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.60.24/osfmk/x86_64/pmap.c:2724
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff92278b39a0 : 0xffffff8011aea53c 
0xffffff92278b3a20 : 0xffffff8011bde5fd 
0xffffff92278b3ac0 : 0xffffff8011be5902 
0xffffff92278b3be0 : 0xffffff8011be693a 
0xffffff92278b3c50 : 0xffffff8011b731a8 
0xffffff92278b3d90 : 0xffffff8011af5925 
0xffffff92278b3dc0 : 0xffffff8011fe20ed 
0xffffff92278b3e10 : 0xffffff8011fc87fa 
0xffffff92278b3e30 : 0xffffff8011f4e260 
0xffffff92278b3ea0 : 0xffffff8011f4def5 
0xffffff92278b3f10 : 0xffffff8011f52a4a 
0xffffff92278b3f50 : 0xffffff80120249c1 
0xffffff92278b3fb0 : 0xffffff8011a9ba88 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: esets_daemon
```

---

```
Anonymous UUID:       8E5573F2-69B7-BEC8-75D7-17581A679C02

Wed May 31 07:59:42 2017

*** MCA Error Report ***
CPU Machine Check Architecture Error Dump (CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz, CPUID: 0x506E3)
CATERR detected! No MCA data found.


*** Device Tree ***
{
    "pcie_cfg_base" : "0xe0000000",
    "pci_devices" :
    {
        "0x8000" : "PEG0@1",
        "0x0" : "MCHC@0",
        "0x9000" : "PEG1@1,1",
        "0xa000" : "PEG2@1,2",
        "0x10000" : "IGPU@2",
        "0x100000" : "PEG0@1/IOPP/GFX0@0",
        "0x101000" : "PEG0@1/IOPP/HDAU@0,1",
        "0xa0000" : "XHC1@14",
        "0xa8000" : "I2C0@15",
        "0xb0000" : "IMEI@16",
        "0xc8000" : "URT2@19",
        "0x8200000" : "PEG1@1,1/IOPP/UPSB@0",
        "0x400000" : "PEG2@1,2/IOPP/UPSB@0",
        "0x8300000" : "PEG1@1,1/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0",
        "0x8308000" : "PEG1@1,1/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@1",
        "0x8310000" : "PEG1@1,1/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2",
        "0x8320000" : "PEG1@1,1/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB4@4",
        "0x8400000" : "PEG1@1,1/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2/IOPP/XHC2@0",
        "0x500000" : "PEG2@1,2/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0",
        "0x8500000" : "PEG1@1,1/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0",
        "0x508000" : "PEG2@1,2/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@1",
        "0x510000" : "PEG2@1,2/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2",
        "0x520000" : "PEG2@1,2/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB4@4",
        "0x600000" : "PEG2@1,2/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2/IOPP/XHC3@0",
        "0x700000" : "PEG2@1,2/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0",
        "0xd8000" : "RP17@1B",
        "0xe0000" : "RP01@1C",
        "0xf0000" : "URT0@1E",
        "0xf1000" : "URT1@1E,1",
        "0xf2000" : "SPI0@1E,2",
        "0x200000" : "RP17@1B/IOPP/SSD0@0",
        "0xf3000" : "SPI1@1E,3",
        "0xf8000" : "LPCB@1F",
        "0xfa000" : "PMCR@1F,2",
        "0xfb000" : "HDEF@1F,3",
        "0xfc000" : "SBUS@1F,4",
        "0x300000" : "RP01@1C/IOPP/ARPT@0"
    },
    "device_mmio" :
    {
        "PCI0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xcf8", "s" : "0x8" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG0@1/IOPP/GFX0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f80000000", "s" : "0x10000000" },
            { "a" : "0x7f90000000", "s" : "0x200000" },
            { "a" : "0x82600000", "s" : "0x40000" },
            { "a" : "0x82640000", "s" : "0x20000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG0@1/IOPP/HDAU@0,1" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x82660000", "s" : "0x4000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG1@1,1/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x82900000", "s" : "0x40000" },
            { "a" : "0x82940000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG1@1,1/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2/IOPP/XHC2@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x82800000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG2@1,2/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xaac00000", "s" : "0x40000" },
            { "a" : "0xaac40000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG2@1,2/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2/IOPP/XHC3@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xaab00000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IGPU@2" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f91000000", "s" : "0x1000000" },
            { "a" : "0x7fa0000000", "s" : "0x10000000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/XHC1@14" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f90210000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/I2C0@15" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f9022a000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IMEI@16" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f90229000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/URT2@19" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f90228000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP17@1B/IOPP/SSD0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x82500000", "s" : "0x4000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP01@1C/IOPP/ARPT@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x82400000", "s" : "0x8000" },
            { "a" : "0x82000000", "s" : "0x400000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/URT0@1E" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f90227000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/URT1@1E,1" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f90226000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SPI0@1E,2" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f90225000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SPI1@1E,3" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f90224000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PMCR@1F,2" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x82724000", "s" : "0x4000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/HDEF@1F,3" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f90220000", "s" : "0x4000" },
            { "a" : "0x7f90200000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SBUS@1F,4" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x7f9022b000", "s" : "0x100" }
        ],
        "DMAC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x0", "s" : "0x20" },
            { "a" : "0x81", "s" : "0x11" },
            { "a" : "0x93", "s" : "0xd" },
            { "a" : "0xc0", "s" : "0x20" }
        ],
        "FWHD" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xff000000", "s" : "0x1000000" }
        ],
        "IPIC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x20", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x24", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x28", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x2c", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x30", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x34", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x38", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x3c", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xa0", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xa4", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xa8", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xac", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xb0", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xb4", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xb8", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xbc", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x4d0", "s" : "0x2" }
        ],
        "MATH" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xf0", "s" : "0x1" }
        ],
        "LDRC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x2e", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x4e", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x61", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x63", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x65", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x67", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x80", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x92", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0xb2", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xffff", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x1800", "s" : "0xff" },
            { "a" : "0x800", "s" : "0x80" }
        ],
        "RTC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x70", "s" : "0x8" }
        ],
        "TIMR" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x40", "s" : "0x4" },
            { "a" : "0x50", "s" : "0x4" }
        ],
        "SMC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x300", "s" : "0x20" },
            { "a" : "0xfef00000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "EC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x62", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x66", "s" : "0x1" }
        ],
        "PDRC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xfed10000", "s" : "0x8000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed18000", "s" : "0x1000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed19000", "s" : "0x1000" },
            { "a" : "0xe0000000", "s" : "0x10000000" },
            { "a" : "0xfd000000", "s" : "0x1800000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed20000", "s" : "0x20000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed90000", "s" : "0x4000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed45000", "s" : "0x4b000" },
            { "a" : "0xff000000", "s" : "0x1000000" },
            { "a" : "0xfee00000", "s" : "0x100000" }
        ],
        "MEM2" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x20000000", "s" : "0x200000" },
            { "a" : "0x40000000", "s" : "0x200000" }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

```
Anonymous UUID:       8E5573F2-69B7-BEC8-75D7-17581A679C02

Tue May 23 18:46:28 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff80129e04fd): "TLB invalidation IPI timeout: " "CPU(s) failed to respond to interrupts, unresponsive CPU bitmap: 0xc0, NMIPI acks: orig: 0x0, now: 0x0"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.51.2/osfmk/x86_64/pmap.c:2724
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff92298f3b60 : 0xffffff80128ec3ec 
0xffffff92298f3be0 : 0xffffff80129e04fd 
0xffffff92298f3c80 : 0xffffff80129e7802 
0xffffff92298f3da0 : 0xffffff80129e883a 
0xffffff92298f3e10 : 0xffffff801296faef 
0xffffff92298f3e50 : 0xffffff801295a094 
0xffffff92298f3ed0 : 0xffffff8012959a92 
0xffffff92298f3f00 : 0xffffff8012959685 
0xffffff92298f3f30 : 0xffffff8012958ec8 
0xffffff92298f3f90 : 0xffffff8012958ccf 
0xffffff92298f3fb0 : 0xffffff801289a8f7 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
16E195

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 06F94FD7-451F-34A1-B13C-D68FF7EDE0A0
Kernel slide:     0x0000000012600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8012800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8012700000
System model name: MacBookPro13,3 (Mac-A5C67F76ED83108C)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 316892881206993
last loaded kext at 316835477051539: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm   5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9671e000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 307907044424136: com.apple.driver.TestDeviceVCOMACMData   1.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9670b000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.eset.kext.esets_kac 401.09.70f01

/* ..... */

com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

---

```
Anonymous UUID:       8E5573F2-69B7-BEC8-75D7-17581A679C02

Tue May 16 18:50:41 2017

*** Panic Report ***
Panic(CPU 7): NMIPI for spinlock acquisition timeout, spinlock: 0xffffff80142892b8, spinlock owner: 0xffffff806d1809a8, current_thread: 0xffffff806d1809a8, spinlock_owner_cpu: 0x7
RAX: 0x000000001a0742ed, RBX: 0xffffff80142e4a60, RCX: 0x0000000009000000, RDX: 0xffffff80142690a8
RSP: 0xffffff81f2ee5e20, RBP: 0xffffff81f2ee5e20, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0xffffff80142690a8
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x000000001a0742ed, R10: 0xffffff8014208e50, R11: 0xffffff80142892b8
R12: 0xffffff80142e4a90, R13: 0xffffff8013b247d0, R14: 0xffffff80142e4a60, R15: 0xffffff81f2ee5ea0
RFL: 0x0000000000000046, RIP: 0xffffff8013a99bdb, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Backtrace (CPU 7), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f2ee5cc0 : 0xffffff8013c005a1 
0xffffff81f2ee5d20 : 0xffffff8013a9d86f 
0xffffff81f2ee5e20 : 0xffffff8013b247ea 
0xffffff81f2ee5e50 : 0xffffff8013b2dd4a 
0xffffff81f2ee5f10 : 0xffffff8013bf35bb 
0xffffff81f2ee5f50 : 0xffffff8013c0909b 
0xffffff81f2ee5f70 : 0xffffff8013c005a1 
0xffffff81f2ee5fd0 : 0xffffff8013a9d709 
0xffffff9229b2b460 : 0xffffff8013be7802 
0xffffff9229b2b580 : 0xffffff8013be883a 
0xffffff9229b2b5f0 : 0xffffff8013b750a8 
0xffffff9229b2b730 : 0xffffff8013b749ac 
0xffffff9229b2b760 : 0xffffff8013b703a3 
0xffffff9229b2b790 : 0xffffff8013af7b8d 
0xffffff9229b2b7b0 : 0xffffff8013af8369 
0xffffff9229b2b7d0 : 0xffffff7f96a8f70d 
0xffffff9229b2b8d0 : 0xffffff8013d60844 
0xffffff9229b2b930 : 0xffffff8013d601d3 
0xffffff9229b2b9e0 : 0xffffff7f95d2d340 
0xffffff9229b2bab0 : 0xffffff8013ffc817 
0xffffff9229b2bba0 : 0xffffff8013b573c8 
0xffffff9229b2bbf0 : 0xffffff8013b57153 
0xffffff9229b2bc30 : 0xffffff8013b66043 
0xffffff9229b2bd60 : 0xffffff8013b6afd6 
0xffffff9229b2bf30 : 0xffffff8013c015ec 
0xffffff9229b2bfb0 : 0xffffff8013a9d455 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext(366.50.19)[0DD51F29-270C-3A03-8125-A68E4D5AB22B]@0xffffff7f95d06000->0xffffff7f95d6efff
            dependency: com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext(1)[18EED417-E0C7-3AE6-8EBB-CB081566B738]@0xffffff7f95cff000
         com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib(1.0)[A8B584B1-03DF-3780-923B-4FD6FF942049]@0xffffff7f96a8d000->0xffffff7f96a92fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: opendirectoryd

Mac OS version:
16E195

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 06F94FD7-451F-34A1-B13C-D68FF7EDE0A0
Kernel slide:     0x0000000013800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8013a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8013900000
System model name: MacBookPro13,3 (Mac-A5C67F76ED83108C)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 447881955998109
last loaded kext at 447827427332757: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm   5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f97891000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 435811883271109: com.apple.driver.TestDeviceVCOMACMData   1.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9787e000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.eset.kext.esets_kac 401.09.70f01
com.logitech.manager.kernel.driver  6.40.1
com.apple.driver.TestDeviceVCOMACMData  1.0.0

/* .... */

com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff8013be9e0c): "Spinlock acquisition timed out: lock=0xffffff80142892b8, lock owner thread=0xffffff806d1809a8, current_thread: 0xffffff8036e53000, lock owner active on CPU 0x7, current owner: 0xffffff806d1809a8"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.51.2/osfmk/i386/locks_i386.c:427
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff920202b7b0 : 0xffffff8013aec3ec 
0xffffff920202b830 : 0xffffff8013be9e0c 
0xffffff920202b870 : 0xffffff8013b6d0ea 
0xffffff920202b980 : 0xffffff8013b756e5 
0xffffff920202bac0 : 0xffffff8013af77d5 
0xffffff920202baf0 : 0xffffff8013fe2c4d 
0xffffff920202bb40 : 0xffffff8013fc93da 
0xffffff920202bb60 : 0xffffff7f9780f114 
0xffffff920202bdb0 : 0xffffff7f97813098 
0xffffff920202bfb0 : 0xffffff8013a9a8f7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.eset.kext.esets_kac(401.9.70f1)[083B2CD0-812D-D765-6EDC-8D003E027A76]@0xffffff7f97808000->0xffffff7f9781cfff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
```

Comment: I'm no expert at this, but I'd be inclined to test without Eset, it's the only commonality I can see.

Answer (score 3):

Get the machine replaced by Apple. I had the same issue with a plethora of crashes similar to yours (lots of TLB invalidation crashes) and since replacement it has been good to go. I was experiencing approx 1 crash per day during sleep.

Comment: I don't know if this is just a coincidence, but I have disabled "Aerial" Screen Saver and no crash happened since... will monitor situation.

Comment: Lol, scratch my previous comment - today another restart and another caused by: "TLB invalidation IPI timeout: "

Comment: same problem here, no eset